# Laptop screen won't turn on. only external monitor works

Tags: display

I have a HP G42 351TX laptop. It gets powered on but without display. When I connect any external monitor via VGA cable it boots up but crashes with BSOD MEMORY DUMP. It is dual boot machine with windows 7 and windows 8.1 installed on it.

**Windows 7 boot error**
[image: Windows 7 boot error]

**Windows 8.1 boot error**
[image: Windows 8.1 boot error]

I have done some research on google for this error code and its related to AMD Drivers but why is my internal display of laptop not working?

I have also tried Safe Mode option but that does't seems to help as computer restarts immediately after BSOD error.

Any help?

Comment: Is there any further information on the error message? Can you take a photo of it or something?

Comment: Sure let me take a screenshot and post it.

Comment: I am getting any option to upload images.

Comment: Upload your image to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get a link you can share. [Edit] your question to include this link and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you.

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Hold a flashlight to your laptop display and see if there's anything, just to rule out backlight failure

Comment: This is some hardware fault as i have tried booting up without hard disk as well as after re-installing operating system. The internal display doesn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like corrupt or missing graphics drivers. The [HP website](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02484885) for this laptop is pretty useless but a little searching provides us with the GPU inside it: [ATI Radeon HD5430](http://notebook-reviewku.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/harga-laptop-hp-g42-351tx-terbaru.html)

You can get the latest drivers from the [AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows%207%20-%2032) website. Give them a try and you should find your graphics is restored to normal.

**EDIT** Apparently this BSOD is occurring almost immediately after Windows has finished booting.

If you hold <kbd>F8</kbd> on boot you can enter safe mode and try it there. Safe mode uses a reduced driver set and puts less stress on the system, this might make it stable enough to perform the driver update.

You could save yourself some time by downloading the drivers on a different PC and using a pendrive to transfer them across.

Comment: Sir how would i be able to get into the system assuming that my computer restarts as soon as the BSOD appears.

Comment: Does it BSOD as soon as Windows is finished loading or a short while afterwards? If the latter you will have to be quick!

Comment: Is there anyhow i can boot into windows and update the driver?

Comment: The final option is to reinstall the PC.

Comment: This is some hardware fault as i have tried booting up without hard disk as well as after re-installing operating system. The internal display doesn't come up.